# Не могу установить Pyaudio в Pycharm

Tags: python

1. Версия

   ```
   Python - Python 3.10.0
   ```
2. Whl документ

   ```
   PyAudio-0.2.11-cp310-cp310-win_amd64
   ```
3. Пытался указать расположение через:

   ```
   C:\Users\Пользователь>cd C:\Users\Пользователь\Downloads
   C:\Users\Пользователь\Downloads>pip install PyAudio-0.2.11-cp310-cp310-win_amd64
   ```

   ```
    <pre>ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyAudio-0.2.11-cp310-cp310-win_amd64 (from versions: none)
   ```

ERROR: No matching distribution found for PyAudio-0.2.11-cp310-cp310-win_amd64

4. Пробовал в Pycharm:

   ```
    <pre>pip install PyAudio</pre>

    <pre>Collecting PyAudio
   ```

```
Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for PyAudio, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: PyAudio
    Running setup.py install for PyAudio ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'
"'C:\\Users\\Пользователь\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-th9cw1nm\\pyaudio_a409bd97d81d43aba8cb459ea9ade962\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\По
льзователь\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-th9cw1nm\\pyaudio_a409bd97d81d43aba8cb459ea9ade962\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)
(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'
"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-9z2xr7ut\install-record.
txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include\PyAudio'
         cwd: C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-th9cw1nm\pyaudio_a409bd97d81d43aba8cb459ea9ade962\
    Complete output (9 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-t
ools/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setupt
ools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Пользователь\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-th9cw1nm\\pyaudio_a409bd97d81d43aba8cb459ea9ade962\\setup.py'
"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Пользователь\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-th9cw1nm\\pyaudio_a409bd97d81d43aba8cb459ea9ade962\\setup.py'"'"';f = getatt
r(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().r
eplace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Temp\pi
p-record-9z2xr7ut\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\
Python310\Include\PyAudio' Check the logs for full command output.
```

В консоли тоже самое

5. Устанавливал:

   ```
   pip install sounddevice
   ```

   Не помогло
6. По разному пробовал:

   ```
   1-) pip install --upgrade pyaudio
   ```

   ```
   2-) pip install pipwin
   ```

Не помогло

1. Вот исходный код:

   ```
   <pre>import os
   ```

```
import sys 
import webbrowser 
import Speech_Recognition as sr 

def talk(words):
    print(words)
    os.system("say" + words)

talk("Привет, спроси у меня что-либо")
```

2. Вот первоначальная ошибка:

   ```
    <pre>Traceback (most recent call last):
   ```

File "C:\Users\Пользователь\PycharmProjects\app\venv\iclude\main.py", line 4, in 
import Speech_Recognition as sr #Сокращение записи, работа со звуком
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Speech_Recognition'

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/ вроде у вас 1 символ лишний _

Comment: error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/   это лечится установкой студии с пакетами, которая 6 гигов весит

Answer (score 0):

Так вроде нужно писать pip install + полное имя файла с расширением.
Попробуйте:

pip install PyAudio-0.2.11-cp310-cp310-win_amd64